Integrate VPN into a windows desktop application
I want to connect the windows desktop clients to a private API server made using .net 6 web api. I can do this right now by using a VPN to connect to the server.
Now I want to give this windows desktop application (windows forms application .NET 6) to 100 users. Can I just integrate the VPN right in the application so that I don't have to ask all 100 users to go through the VPN process.
If yes, then how can I do this?
